# Extension en Visual Studio Code para trabajar con repositorio remoto

Tags: vscode

usualmente estoy trabajando en algunos scripts que se encuentran en un repositorio remoto gigantesco, el cual no quiero clonar localmente. Tienen alguna sugerencia de alguna extension que me permita accesar a ese repositorio a traves de FTP/Sftp? Desgargue ftp-simple, sin embargo algunas carpetas la tiene que descargar o sinconizar (no se) y como el repositorio es tan grande no las abre a tarda mucho en sincornizar.

Anteriomente en Atom usaba remote-ftp, hay alguna similar en VCodeS?

Answer (score 0):

Pues todo dependerá de como quieras trabajar con el proyecto.

Si lo que quieres es mantener el código en el repositorio remoto y trabajar con el directamente puedes usar la extensión [Remote - SSH](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh)

Si lo que quieres es mantener tu código en local y que se actualice automáticamente con el servidor remoto puedes usar la extensión [SFTP](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=liximomo.sftp).

La extensión SFTP es muy completa, permite trabajar con varios servidores, sincronización automática... Su configuración no es extremadamente complicada, puedes ver una configuración base de la misma en mi propio repositorio [VSCode-settings](https://github.com/oscarnovasf/VSCode-settings) - es el archivo sftp.json-.

Comment: ¿Y cuál sería la respuesta única? No la hay, porque la pregunta simplemente pide recomendaciones de herramientas y opiniones. Te invito a leer [answer]. Responder este tipo de preguntas que no aportan nada es una pérdida, ya que terminan cerradas y tu respuesta se pierde. Te sugiero que evites responder este tipo de preguntas. Saludos